# Offsetting co-planar mesh depth based on drawing order

Tags: opengl

I have the following issue: In my application I render planes in a layered fashion with depth buffer on.In some cases 2 or more such layers can be co-planar in which case the one which is higher in the layer stack index should be the overlapping one.I know that I can basically doing polygon offset to set some offset to prevent z -fighting but it means I need to compare between different layer to determine which ones are co-planar.Also I am worried about to much offsets accumulation. Is it possible to do such an offset in a fragment shader for example?

Comment: One suggestion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432934/techniques-for-drawing-coplanar-polygons-in-opengl

Comment: That means I must sort the geometry. I am asking if it's possible to avoid it.

Comment: When a fragment fails the depth test, the fragment shader will not run, so as long as you have depth testing on.. it is too late at that stage. I don't think you can avoid comparing the layers in this case.